# Why are there so many settings.php files one in each folder or sub-directory?

Tags: configuration

I am Drupal newbie taking over a poorly documented D6 group of sites organized by sub-domains. In examining the dev.[domain].org/sites/ folder I discover folders: all, default, demo.[domain].org and [customer].[domain].org and each folder has its own settings.php?

For example, /default/settings.php allows me to configure-or-edit the 'site_name' => and $db_url and $base_url. The $db_url works.

while, /all/settings.php has a disabled # $base_url and a disabled # 'site_name' => yet an active $db_url that is connecting to a 'mysql://[detail]' that may or may not be an active db.

I presume folders demo.[domain].org and [customer].[domain].org in the /sites/ folder are just legacy folders left by the previous coder/hacker of the settings.php used in the those sub-domains.

Your thoughts and answers will be gratefully consumed.

Thank you, Steve

Answer (score 3):

Refer the multisite doc as Molot suggested. We don't know how your site(s) have set up, so you have to experiment it yourself.

> Q1: Why isn't there just one settings.php per sub-domain site?

There is. `sub.example.com` site's `settings.php` file is `sites/sub.example.com/settings.php`. The reason to have a whole folder is to make it possible for you to store files, modules, themes and libraries separately (`sites/sub.example.com/modules` will be only available to `sub.example.com` likewise.)

> Q2: What is the difference between /default/settings.php and
>   /all/settings.php?

You should not have a `settings.php` file in `sites/all` folder. That folder is a special one that is used to store common files across all the sites, and the default modules/themes/libraries folder for the only site if it's not a multisite.

> Q3: And why are folders demo.[domain].org and [customer].[domain].org
>   in the /sites/ folder? Perhaps they are just legacy folders left by
>   the previous coder/hacker of the settings.php used in the those
>   sub-domains.

If there are `demo.example.com` site, that site is *probably* using the settings.php inside to load the settings. You can however change this in the `sites/sites.php` file. Unless you override, `demo.example.com` site is using `sites/demo.example.com/settings.php`.